# Marionette ItemView trying to render template before fetch in init completes

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

**UPDATE**

I've created a work around for my project.  I set an empty template to be this views default template (actually contains loading message and throbber in case of any further delays) and set the model change event to replace the views $el html with the groupTemplate when it's ready.  This makes a seemless transition on my dev, test and production box, however, if production gets slow while retreiving the model's data, it will actually get to show the loading message.

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'marionette',
  'models/group',
  'text!templates/shared/empty.html', // include empty template
  'text!templates/groups/group.html'
], function(_, Backbone, Marionette, groupModel, emptyTemplate, groupTemplate){
  var GroupView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      var view = this;

      this.model = new groupModel({id:this.options.groupid});

      // listen to the model change and display the real template when fired.
      this.model.on('change', function(){
        view.$el.html(_.template(groupTemplate, view.model.attributes));
      });

      this.model.fetch();
    },
    template: emptyTemplate // display empty template be default
  });
  return GroupView;
});
```

I have a single layout using nested column layouts (three column in this case).  The nested layouts are called with the corresponding views and it requires those views and shows them in it's own regions. (if there is a better way to do this, please let me know).

My problem is the GroupView for col2 (nested three-column layout) is using an ItemView and is using a model that has no data to start.  The model retreives the data using a url and not from a collection, so a fetch must be used to retreive the data.  The ItemView is trying to render it's template using a model with no data and fails to find the model fields.  Giving me the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: groupname is not defined

Is there a way to delay rendering or does ItemView have an undocumented emptyView like the colletionsView?  If there is a better way to handle this, please let me know.

Router Controller

```
group: function(groupid) {
  // require and setup our three column layout
  require([
    'views/layouts/three-column', 'views/shared/left-user-menu',
    'views/groups/group', 'views/shared/location'
  ], function(threeColumnLayout, leftView, groupView, locationView) {
  App.wrapper.currentView.main.show(new threeColumnLayout({
    views: {
      col1: new leftView(),
      col2: new groupView({groupid: groupid}),
      col3: new locationView()}
  }));
}
```

Nested Layout (three-column)

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'marionette',
  'text!templates/layouts/three-column.html'
], function(_, Backbone, Marionette, threeColumnTemplate) {
  var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
      var layout = this;

      this.on('render', function(options){
        layout.col1.show(options.options.views.col1);
        layout.col2.show(options.options.views.col2);
        layout.col3.show(options.options.views.col3);
      });
    },
    tagName: 'div',
    template: threeColumnTemplate,
    regions: {
      col1: '#col1',
      col2: '#col2',
      col3: '#col3'
    }
  });

  return Layout;
});
```

Group ItemView

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'marionette',
  'models/group',
  'text!templates/groups/group.html'
], function(_, Backbone, Marionette, groupModel, groupTemplate){
  var GroupView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.model = new groupModel({id:this.options.groupid});
      this.model.fetch();
    },
    template: groupTemplate
  });
  return GroupView;
});
```

Comment: Look at Marionette.Async.  It's designed to make `show` work with asynchronous requests.

Comment: @tkone I tried to use the async module, but the rest of my project quit working.  It appears to be an all or nothing type.  Also I'm override the TemplateCache with one that will work with RequireJS and text templates... so that was acting weird as well.  I'm going to continue to look into the async module and see if I was using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Fetch and then render when you know your data is ready. Use promises to make it easy as backbone fetches return promises already.

```
initialize: function () {
  var that = this;
  var fetching = this.model.fetch();

  fetching.done(function() { that.render(); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem

[Backbone Marionette Displaying before fetch complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317691/backbone-marionette-displaying-before-fetch-complete)

```
this.model = new groupModel({id:this.options.groupid});
```

will fire render because there is an object being passed. before getting the fetch
..

My normal workaround was to set a blank default for anything that the template needs before the fetch hydrates the object.

Comment: you could also modify the fetch to instead of fetching from the id. if id is not set fetch by some accessible (namespaced window.) variable

Comment: This gave me an idea for my loading.  I have an empty template that I set to be the views default template, then on the model change event, I replace the view's $el.html with the new template and the model's attributes.  All works well.  I'm thinking that an empty template per view for defaults (maybe even a loading throbber image) will work better for each view.  I'll add it to the main question above.

Comment: "My normal workaround was to set a blank default for anything that the template needs before the fetch hydrates the object"  All well and good, but Marionette is supposed to *reduce* boilerplate :(

Comment: It does... this "bug" is more a function of Backbone than marionette. (Its actually more of an intended action)